# How to semantically code an HTML nested table that aligns (and associates) with its parent table's headers

Tags: html, html-table, semantic-markup

Edit: The selected answer contains a link to the working fiddle I was able to compose without the use of a nested table.

I want to semantically code a table in HTML with a layout like the picture below. Unfortunately I haven't been able to find anything quite like it here on the network.

[image]

I have been able to force the look by manually setting cell widths, but I want to make sure the code I'm producing makes sense, and I don't think that's the case, because without manually setting the widths, standard rendering looks more like the following picture.

[image]

So far, the problematic code I have come up with looks like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Type of Loss Dollar</th>
      <th scope="col">Reserve Amount</th>
      <th scope="col">Paid Amount</th>
      <th scope="col">Total This Loss</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">Medical</th>
              <td><input type="text" /></td>
              <td><input type="text" /></td>
            </tr><tr>
              <th scope="row">Indemnity</th>
              <td><input type="text" /></td>
              <td><input type="text" /></td>
            </tr><tr>
              <th scope="row">Expense</th>
              <td><input type="text" /></td>
              <td><input type="text" /></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td><td>
        TOTAL
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Don't use a table in a table. Use *one* table. Problem solved.

Comment: Once the images are available, the issue will become clearer. Again, sorry for the delay.

Comment: the answer easy on html, hard on serverside :/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Without the images it's a bit hard to say, but I think a better solution than nested tables would be to simply use the `colspan` and `rowspan` attributes.

Edit: Seeing the images I'd say you can most definitely achieve that using `rowspan` (and `colspan` the way you're using it already).

Also, you don't need to set the `scope` attribute if it's "col". It defaults to "col".

Edit: As Marat Tanalin points out the `scope` attribute's default value is actually `auto` which "makes the header cell apply to a set of cells selected based on context". And which in my experience acts exactly the same as setting it to "col" (for screenreaders).

Edit: Here are two great articles on marking up advanced tables: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200910/use_the_th_element_to_specify_row_and_column_headers_in_data_tables/ & http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200410/bring_on_the_tables/

Edit: [Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DWM4T/) exhibiting desired behavior (visually at least) and the source code of that fiddle follows:

```
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Type of Loss Dollar</th>
      <th>Reserve Amount</th>
      <th>Paid Amount</th>
      <th>Total This Loss</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">Open</td>
      <td>Medical</td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td rowspan="3">TOTAL</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Indemnity</td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Expense</td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes I was not too keen on nesting them, but I couldn't think of another solution. Perhaps my understanding of `colspan` and `rowspan` are insufficient. Thanks for the tip on scope as well.

Comment: Again it would be easier with the images, but I believe you can achieve what you're after using `rowspan` and `colspan`. I'm not even sure nesting tables is ever semantically correct, would a screen reader associate your `th`s with the nested `table`s `td`s? I'm not so sure.

Comment: Ok the images are up, and I'd definitely say you can solve this using `rowspan`. Would set up a fiddle but I don't have the time right now, and tbh I haven't used `rowspan` since the days of table layouts :P

Comment: @powerbuoy It would be nice that you provide proof link for your statement about `col` as `scope`'s default value. HTML5 [says](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-th-element.html#attr-th-scope): "The scope attribute's missing value default is the auto state."

Comment: @powerbuoy [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DWM4T/) of what I've come up with that looks like what I need, but I'm not sure it could really be called semantic. What do you think? I may just have to leave it at "pragmatic".

Comment: @EvanDriscoll - I'd definitely say that's the way to go.

Comment: @MaratTanalin - Ah ok, but in my experience not setting and setting it to "col" does exactly the same thing (for screenreaders at least).

Answer (score 1):

yep, as all the peeps above suggested, it's all about the rowspan.

here's a re-write of your code:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Type of Loss Dollar</th>
      <th>Reserve Amount</th>
      <th>Paid Amount</th>
      <th>Total This Loss</th>
      <th>Last Heading</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3"></td>
      <td>Medical</td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td rowspan="3">TOTAL</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Indemnity</td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Expense</td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The first `td` is unclosed (just so you know). Thank you for your time regardless. I think I've found what I need in the fiddle I linked to (in powerbuoy's answer), but if you have any suggestions on how it could be made more semantically correct, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Medical has a </th> instead of </td>