# How to create nested table in html

Tags: html, html-table, datatable, nested-table

I need to create an HTML table with an inner table like the below-given diagram:

[Example][1]
I'm confused if I should create two separate tables for both left side and right side table or combine them together in a single table

I tried below example, but it's not getting generated in the format I want, basically, it's not generating the inner HTML table:

```
<table >

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>VITAL SIGNS</th>
      <th>FREQUENCY</th>
      <th></th>
      <th>TOTAL SUPPORT</th>
      <th>ASSIST</th>
      <th>SEE CARE</th>
      <th>FREQUENCY</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Temperature</th>
      <th><input type="text" /></th>
      <th>SKIN CARE</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>BP</th>
      <th><input type="text" /></th>
      <th>APPLY LOTION</th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" /></th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" /></th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" /></th>
      <th><input type="text" /></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Pulse</th>
      <th><input type="text" /></th>
      <th>ACTIVITY</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Respiration</th>
      <th><input type="text" /></th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" />
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" /></th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" /></th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" /></th>
      <th><input type="text" /></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>
        <th>TOTAL SUPPORT</th>
        <th>ASSIST</th>
        <th>SELF CARE</th>
        <th>FREQUENCY</th>
      </th>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Duplicate of [How to nest a table within a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43082986/how-to-nest-a-table-within-a-table)

Comment: See also [How to semantically code an HTML nested table that aligns (and associates) with its parent table's headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791541/how-to-semantically-code-an-html-nested-table-that-aligns-and-associates-with)

Comment: And [Nesting Tables Using HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450785/nesting-tables-using-html)

Answer (score 7):

You need to remember that tables will try to equal their cells out to make sure it is a complete and closed table. So to translate the printed table into HTML, requires 'merging' cells by using the HTML properties **colspan** and **rowspan**.
It's tough to translate a print table like that into HTML, without issue. The table will always adapt to the content and the screen.

Here is a (very) **crude** representation of how you *could* structure it, however some of the checkbox items could even be grouped inside one cell, rather than breaking them out into separate cells. However, that would require a slight restructure if you were to group anything.

```html
<style>
   table, td {border-collapse: collapse;}
   td {border:1px solid black; padding:5px; font-size:10px;}
</style>

<table style="width:100%;">
   <tr>
      <td colspan="3" width="10%" bgcolor="#8f9bff">VITAL SIGNS</td>
      <td colspan="4" width="30%" bgcolor="#8f9bff">FREQUENCY</td>
      <td colspan="2" width="10%"></td>
      <td width="30" bgcolor="#b47cff">TOTAL SUPPORT</td>
      <td width="30" bgcolor="#b47cff">ASSIST</td>
      <td width="30" bgcolor="#b47cff">SEE CARE</td>
      <td bgcolor="#b47cff">FREQUENCY</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Temperature</td>
      <td colspan="4"></td>
      <td colspan="6" bgcolor="#8f9bff">SKIN CARE</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="3">BP</td>
      <td colspan="4"></td>
      <td colspan="2">Apply Lotion</td>
      <td>&#10063;</td>
      <td>&#10063;</td>
      <td>&#10063;</td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Pulse</td>
      <td colspan="4"></td>
      <td colspan="6" bgcolor="#8f9bff">ACTIVITY</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Respiration</td>
      <td colspan="4"></td>
      <td>Ambu...</td>
      <td>Mob...</td>
      <td>&#10063;</td>
      <td>&#10063;</td>
      <td>&#10063;</td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#b47cff">TOTAL SUPPORT</td>
      <td bgcolor="#b47cff">ASSIST</td>
      <td bgcolor="#b47cff">SEE CARE</td>
      <td bgcolor="#b47cff">FREQUENCY</td>
      <td>Walker</td>
      <td>Wheelchair</td>
      <td rowspan="2">&#10063;</td>
      <td rowspan="2">&#10063;</td>
      <td rowspan="2">&#10063;</td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="7" bgcolor="#8f9bff">BATH</td>
      <td colspan="2">Cane</td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>&#10063; Tub</td>
      <td colspan="2">&#10063; Shower</td>
      <td>&#10063;</td>
      <td>&#10063;</td>
      <td>&#10063;</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Chair</td>
      <td>Bed</td>
      <td>&#10063;</td>
      <td>&#10063;</td>
      <td>&#10063;</td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Bed</td>
      <td>&#10063; Partial</td>
      <td>&#10063; Complete</td>
      <td>&#10063;</td>
      <td>&#10063;</td>
      <td>&#10063;</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Dang...</td>
      <td>...mmod</td>
      <td>&#10063;</td>
      <td>&#10063;</td>
      <td>&#10063;</td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Assist Bath-Chair</td>
      <td>&#10063;</td>
      <td>&#10063;</td>
      <td>&#10063;</td>
      <td></td>
      <td colspan="2">Exercise</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```